# Unitary transformation of bosonic operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory

Consider two sets of bosonic operators $\{b^{\dagger}_k, b_k\}$ and $\{B^{\dagger}_i, B_i\}$ satisfying $[b_k,b^{\dagger}_{k^{\prime}}]=\delta_{kk^{\prime}}$ and $[B_i,B^{\dagger}_j]=\delta_{ij}$. The ground state (of the kth mode) is defined according to the action of the annihilator $b_k$

$$b_k |0\rangle =0$$

on the bosonic Fock space vacuum $|0\rangle$. Consider now the unitary transformation

$$b_k=\displaystyle\sum_i t_{ki}B_i,
\hspace{0.5cm}
B_i=\displaystyle\sum_k t^{\star}_{ik}b_k \, .
$$

Is it correct to show the invariance of the bosonic many-particle ground state $b_k|0\rangle=0$ under the unitary transformation introduced above, i.e., $B_i|0\rangle=0$ according to the following reasoning

$$B_i| 0 \rangle =\displaystyle\sum_k t^{\star}_{ik}b_k|0\rangle = 0 \, ?$$

The last equality should follow from $b_k|0\rangle = 0$.

Comment: $\uparrow$ Yes.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Despite I posted this question already some time ago, can somebody elaborate on the nature of the two vacua? I guess the left one in the last equation is the vacuum for operators $B_i$, while on the right-hand side, one should have the vacuum for operators $b_k$. Why does there seem to be no difference between them?